# google custom search api c#

Tags: c#, web-services, google-api

I have a c# webservice that uses `WebClient.Downloadstring(MYURL)` to get a Google page.

MYURL is equal to:

> http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mystringtosearch&as_qdr=all&num=100&start=0

It was working fine until i got `503` errors from Google for being a bot. I then got sent here:

> https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

and got a key. Now it says all I need to do is add the `&key` parameter. However, when I have this as MYURL i still get a `503`

> http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mystringtosearch&key=1234567890&as_qdr=all&num=100&start=0

The Google API console says that I haven't done any searches, so I know I haven't gone over my quota.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your custom search engine id in the URL.. as the documentation states, thats what the `cx` parameter is for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using correct url?
Your my url is not customsearch api's url?

If you look at documantation of custom search which is this:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest?hl=tr

yuo can retrieve results for a particular search by sending an HTTP GET request to its URI. The URI for a search has the following format:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?parameters

documantation has more info